# How To Find 2 Minimum Numbers Row and Column From Array Multidimensional in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array in PHP like below

```
$tabel = array(
             array(8,10,9),
             array(10,8,3)
         );
```

and I want to find the 2 minimum numbers by row and column from that array.

Before it I only have to calculate from no array multidimensional, the code like below

```
<?php
    $baris1 = array(8,16,20,10,10);
    $n1 = $n2 = 1000 ; 
    $m1 = $m2 = -1 ;
    for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($array); $i++) {
            $x = $array[$i] ;      
            if ($x <= $n1){
                $n2 = $n1 ;            
                $n1 = $x ;
            } elseif ($x < $n2){
                $n2 = $x;
            }
    }
    echo "Min Number = $n1 $n2<br>";
```

Comment: What do you mean by "calculcate". Are you looking to walk the array and return the minimum numbers from each array?

Comment: yes i mean return the minimum number

Comment: The minimum for each nested array, or the absolute minimum across all the nested arrays?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "2 minimum number row and column"? Are you looking for the two lowest numbers, or the coordinates of the two lowest numbers? Can you provide an example output given the input you've shown?

Comment: @Don'tPanic yes i want to looking for two lowest number

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do it is to merge them all together into one array.

```
$all = array_merge(...$tabel);

// or for PHP < 5.6
// $all = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $tabel);
```

Then you can sort that and take the first two values.

```
sort($all);
$min_two = array_slice($all, 0, 2);
```

For your input example where `$tabel = [[8,10,9], [10,8,3]];`, the result would be `[3, 8]`.

Comment: What PHP version are you using? If it's older it may not support argument unpacking (`...$tabel`).

Comment: how if using for like this code 
`$array = array("77", "5", "99", "40", "50", "6", "17", "70", "100");

    $n1 = $n2 = 1000 ;  // some high number
    $m1 = $m2 = -1 ;

    //This loop is to get max and min value from array
    for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($array); $i++) {
        $x = $array[$i] ; 
        
        //min        
        if ($x <= $n1){
            $n2 = $n1 ;            
            $n1 = $x ;
        } elseif ($x < $n2){
            $n2 = $x;
        }`